# How do I install signal so I can install Octave?

Tags: installation, package-management, octave

anyone can help me with this error?

```
octave:4> pkg install signal-1.2.0.tar.gz
error: the following dependencies where unsatisfied:
   signal needs optim >= 1.0.0
 signal needs specfun >= 0.0.0
 signal needs control >= 2.2.3
 signal needs general >= 1.3.2
octave:4> pkg install optim-1.2.2.tar.gz
error: the following dependencies where unsatisfied:
   optim needs miscellaneous >= 1.0.10
 optim needs struct >= 1.0.10
octave:4> pkg install struct-1.0.10.tar.gz
make: /usr/bin/mkoctfile: Command not found
make: *** [fields2cell.oct] Error 127
'make' returned the following error: make: Entering directory `/tmp/oct-fDBs5k/struct-1.0.10/src'
/usr/bin/mkoctfile -s fields2cell.cc
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/oct-fDBs5k/struct-1.0.10/src'
error: called from `pkg>configure_make' in file /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/pkg/pkg.m near line 1391, column 9
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 834, column 5
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 383, column 9
```

I need to install signal package, but I have to download other to work from I have noticed but it gets stuck when installing struct package.

@edit
The same error when trying to install misc~ package.

```
octave:5> pkg install miscellaneous-1.2.0.tar.gz
error: the following dependencies where unsatisfied:
   miscellaneous needs general >= 1.3.1
octave:5> pkg install general-1.3.2.tar.gz
make: /usr/bin/mkoctfile: Command not found
make: *** [__exit__.oct] Error 127
'make' returned the following error: make: Entering directory `/tmp/oct-CA6o4U/general/src'
/usr/bin/mkoctfile __exit__.cc
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/oct-CA6o4U/general/src'
error: called from `pkg>configure_make' in file /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/pkg/pkg.m near line 1391, column 9
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 834, column 5
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 383, column 9
```

@edit
additional info:

```
octave:6> which mkoctfile
`mkoctfile' is a function from the file /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/miscellaneous/mkoctfile.m
```

I have no idea what to do..

Answer (score 3):

You can install `signal` by entering the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install octave-signal
```

This will install `signal-1.1.3`, at least in Ubuntu Quantal. If you actually need `signal-1.2.0`, the following commands will help you.

1. Install dependencies from Ubuntu archives:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev octave-optim octave-specfun octave-control
   ```
2. Download the latest version of octave `general` [package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/general/index.html) (>=1.3.2) and install it:

   ```
   sudo octave --eval 'pkg install general-1.3.2.tar.gz'
   ```
3. Finally, install the `signal-1.2.0` package:

   ```
   sudo octave --eval 'pkg install signal-1.2.0.tar.gz'
   ```